# Is there a way to change a file name dynamically?

Tags: php

I have a site where only about five people can log into it. When a user logs in I want to have one of the access-protected pages file name to change and have a random file name each time they login. I want this so when the user logs in they cannot type the page in the URL and go straight there by skipping the pages they must go through to get there.

So is this possible with PHP? and any guidance on how to implement this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds not very secure... Ever thought about a real solution for user management?

Comment: Security through obscurity is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

Check php manual for function called 'rename' (the name tells everything): http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Random name could be achieved i.e. by calling: `md5(time())`.

Comment: `md5(time())` is not wise. Try `var_dump(md5(time()),md5(time()));`.

Comment: If you want to rename many files in one script it is not the best way obviously. I am aware of that. However I think that when we create a random name we always should check if the new name does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can rename files.
From http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
rename ( string $oldname , string $newname [, resource $context ] )
```

and http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

```
function random_string($l = 10){
$c = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwz0123456789";
for(;$l > 0;$l--) $s .= $c{rand(0,strlen($c))};
return str_shuffle($s);
```

}

Combine these two to get random file names. (Either store old name somewhere or just check it every time you're about to change it)

```
 function random_string($l = 10){
    $c = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwz0123456789";
    for(;$l > 0;$l--) $s .= $c{rand(0,strlen($c))};
    return str_shuffle($s); }

      $newName=random_string(); // you can enter the length of file you want
    rename ('index.php', $newName.'.php');
```

Comment: So if I am trying to rename the file, "index.php" how would I implement it in the PHP rename you have here? And then store it in a variable so I can use it on another page? Thanks

Comment: $newName= random_string(); //You can put in the length of the name
rename ('index.php', $newName'.php');

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error when I put this.. I put it all in your code above...

Comment: okay this makes sense, however the name is changed permanently right? So how would I change the name again if the name isn't index.php the next time? this code wouldn't work.

Comment: this is why i said you should store the new name somewhere. Write it into some "names.txt" file, or add it into database and next time you need to change the name, read the old one from wherever you wrote it, and change it again

Comment: This name change is also not working. I've tested it over and over and nothing happens to the name index.php